# Cant access graphql in production from node/react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, apollo

i just deployed my react+node+graphql app to DigitalOcean, the visuals is there, however its not able to reach my graphql url endpoint /graphql.

The error im getting is:

> [Network error]: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

And this is the code im using.

Server.js

```
  app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true
  }))

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use( express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

    app.get('*', (req, res)=>{
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    })
  }

const port = app.get('port') || 3002;
  app.listen(port, () => console.log(`The server is running and listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Index.js // here i inject the url that my client should use

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'myproductionurl/graphql',
});
```

Does anyone know why this fails?